# Validating email confirmation and sending different emails to admins

Tags: c#, asp.net, email

I wrote a method that will confirm email with token send to user emails. It will also send different email depending on the condition for the registered user. If anyone would write the same method, how would you write this code snippet?

```
[AllowAnonymous, Route("confirm-email", Name = AccountControllerRoute.GetConfirmEmail)]
public async Task<ActionResult> ConfirmEmail(int accountId, string token)
{
    if (accountId == 0 || token == null)
        return HttpNotFound();

    var account = await AccountManager.FindByIdAsync(accountId);

    if (account == null)
        return HttpNotFound();

    if (account.EmailConfirmed)
        return View("ConfirmEmail"); //return page that will say the token has expired

    var result = await AccountManager.ConfirmEmailAsync(accountId, token);

    var emailBody = string.Empty;
    if (result.Succeeded)
    {
        if(account.Institution == null)
        {
            // send message notifying admin that a new institution needs review and setup
            emailBody = $"{account.UserName}|{account.profile.contact}|{account.profile.institutionName}|{account.profile.institutionAddress}";
            await AccountManager.SendEmailAsync(account.Id, EmailNames.NewInstitutionRequest, "");

            return View("ConfirmEmail");
        }

         // Pass Name, Username
        emailBody = $"{account.Name}|{account.UserName}";

        if (account.Institution.IsClient)
        {
            if (account.Institution.Licence.AllowedAccounts == 0)
            {
                await AccountManager.SendEmailAsync(account.Id, EmailNames.NewUserRequest, emailBody);
                return View("ConfirmEmail"); // send a different message notifying admin about exceeding allow accounts
            }

            // send message notifying admin that a new user request for access
            await AccountManager.SendEmailAsync(account.Id, EmailNames.NewUserRequest, emailBody);
            return View("ConfirmEmail"); 
        }
        else
        {
            // send message notifying admin that a new user has registered
            await AccountManager.SendEmailAsync(account.Id, EmailNames.NewUserNotificationForSA, emailBody);

            return View("ConfirmEmail");
        }
    }

    return View("Error");
}
```

Also, could there be a better way to just pass an object rather than a string with a separator that I have to use to parse them, once passed to a method where it send an email to the user?

```
public class PostalEmailService : IIdentityMessageService
{
    public Task SendAsync(IdentityMessage message)
    {
        if (message == null)
            throw new ArgumentNullException("message");

        EmailBase email;
        switch (message.Subject)
        {
            case EmailNames.ResetPassword:
                email = new ResetPasswordEmail {To = message.Destination, Link = message.Body};
                break;

            case EmailNames.NewUserRequest:
                string name = message.Body.Split('|')[0];
                string userName = message.Body.Split('|')[1];
                email = new NewUserRequestEmail { To = "dummy@gmail.com", Name = name, UserName = userName };
                break;
            default:
                throw new InvalidOperationException("Unknown email '{0}'.".FormatWith(message.Subject));
        }

        return email.SendAsync();
    }
}
```

Comment: I have rolled back the last edit. Please see *[What to do when someone answers](http://codereview.stackexchange.com/help/someone-answers)*.

Comment: @Mast apology for that =)

Answer (score 2):

I'm a bit confused by this:

if (account.EmailConfirmed)
    return View("ConfirmEmail"); //return page that will say the token has expired

Your comment doesn't correspond with the actual code, especially when that same view is returned elsewhere.

---

The `if (result.Succeeded)` should be inverted to avoid 30 lines of indentation. Why not do `if (!result.Succeeded)` and `return View("Error");` immediately afterwards?

Also, `result` is a fairly meaningless name.

---

I don't know what you're doing with `emailBody`, but judging from its format and the comments it looks like you're using it to pass arguments in a delimiter-separated string. That's odd, to say the least.

I also don't see the point of compiling it inside `if(account.Institution == null)` and then not using its value.

---

What happens inside `if (account.Institution.Licence.AllowedAccounts == 0)` looks to be exactly the same as what happens if that isn't the case.

---

What is `EmailNames`? An `enum`? I don't think that class should have a plural name, and it doesn't look like it is an "email name".

Comment: I don't agree with the last statement, classes with contants-only, may have plural names. I do this all the time ie for`ColumnNames`

Comment: @t3chb0t Even in such cases I don't see why. To me `ColumnNames.ID` is an odd construct, since it will return the name of one column. But there are no hard rules, it's just an opinion (except for collection classes, certain types of enum,...).

Comment: haha, on the contrary I would never give a collection class a plural name   - so we're even? ;-P

Comment: `EmailsNames` is a class with constant properties. defining which type of emails will be used.

Comment: `if (account.Institution.Licence.AllowedAccounts == 0)` it will look the same but it has different email template that will be sent to admin.

Comment: `if (account.EmailConfirmed) return View("ConfirmEmail"); //return page that will say the token has expired`, apoligies not being clear with this this will have a different view that contains message the generated token for email confirmation has already been processed. right now I don't have yet the knowledge to create some kind of process to make the token expired so once the `email_confirmed` in the database has been set to `TRUE` then it means it has been used already.

Comment: "I also don't see the point of compiling it inside if(account.Institution == null) and then not using its value." I have to check if the account is associated to an institution then I have to do something, I don't need to process it's data.

Comment: "I don't know what you're doing with emailBody, but judging from its format and the comments it looks like you're using it to pass arguments in a delimiter-separated string. That's odd, to say the least." I wish a could pass object to the method from an `Identity` that sending an email message so I don't have to do that.